satake parameter of contragredient representation
I’m studying representation theory.
Let $F$ a $p$-adic field. Let $\pi$ be an unranufied representation of $\mathrm{GL}_n(F)$. In this case, is the Satake parameter of contragredient representation of $\pi$ the reciprocal of the Satake parameter of $\pi$
Please tell me its proof or counter example.
Thank you.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
